# Deploy war on Tomcat without the war name in the URL

Tags: deployment, tomcat

I built a war file called `myapp.war` and deployed it on **Tomcat**.  I've changed the port from **8080** to **80** so I can then get to it at `example.com/myapp` (where `example.com` is my host).

How can I get configure the application so that when I go to `example.com`, it shows my app?  I don't want to just redirect from `example.com` to `example.com/myapp` - I don't want to have `myapp` in the URL.
Do I have to set up Apache to serve the pages like this, or can I do it with a virtual host in the Tomcat configuration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need to do is name your war `ROOT.war`.

Comment: No, this is not enough, you need to remove the current default application first (i.e. delete the ROOT directory) for this method.

Comment: That's not true, Tomcat will expand the WAR and overwrite the ROOT directory (for all recent versions of Tomcat) if it is restarted.

Comment: Oh, indeed, forget what I said. But it is worth mentioning that it will be overwritten then.

Comment: True enough.  But if he didn't know about ROOT.war before, then he's just got the default app there.

Answer (score 8):

Here are two possible method:

1. Rename your war to ROOT.war
2. No need to rename. Go to `CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` Find Host element and set `autoDeploy="false"` `deployOnStartup="false"` then add `<Context path="" docBase="your_project_name"/>` in the end like:

expamle#2:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false"> 

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    <Context path="" docBase="your_project_name"/><!--Add this-->
  </Host>
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't **have to** setup an Apache front-end or to configure virtual hosting in Tomcat for this. Instead, just deploy your webapp to the "root context". To do this, refer to [How do I make my web application be the Tomcat default application ?](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application_.3F) on the Tomcat Wiki. They describe the three possible methods so you'll be able to pickup the one that suits the best your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Tomcat virtual hosting howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html).