# Getting the application structure correct when using Warbler to make a .war

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tomcat

The instructions in Warbler say that I should run it at the root of the directory structure of an application.

The index.html ended up being not in the root directory of the .war so it caused problems.

Here is my just-ruby server:

```
http://128.48.204.195:3000/
```

It works fine, but then, when I used warbler and put the war into tomcat, here is what happens:

```
http://128.48.204.195:8080/blog/index.html
```

What is causing this kind of mis-match-ness of the directory structures? How is this typically handled?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding you correctly, you want to access this link:
`'http://128.48.204.195:8080/blog/index.html'`

but you to type this url:

`http://128.48.204.195:8080/index.html`

and your application is deployed into tomcat inside the /webapps folder.  By default tomcat thinks you want your app to be under its own subcontext hence the '../blog/...' [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031537/deploy-war-on-tomcat-without-the-war-name-in-the-url)