# Spring Rest HelloWorld app with Gradle without SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

How can I make my Spring Rest HelloWorld app work without using Spring Boot?

When running this project in tomcat 8.5 within eclipse, I expect the url "localhost:8080/hello" to show "HelloWorld", but instead it shows 404

src/main/java/com.package/HelloController.java

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

src/main/java/com.package/HelloConfig.java

```
public class HelloConfig {

    @Bean
    public HelloController helloController() {
        return new HelloController();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloConfig.class);
        context.getBean(HelloController.class);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'eclipse-wtp'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.3.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: How is the rest of the configuration looks like? How do you deploy the app?

Comment: Did you configure your controller as a bean or set up component scanning?

Comment: You probably have some extra context in the url. Try `localhost:8080/<name of your war file>/hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: the missing bit was the DispatcherServlet, the logic responsible for delegating http requests to Controllers, like HelloController in my example.

Based on Spring docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet), there are 3 ways to configure DispatcherServlet:

1. in web.xml
2. overriding WebApplicationInitializer
3. extending AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer (recommended for apps with Java based configurations like mine)

src/main/java/com.package/ServletInitializer:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { HelloConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

note: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to WebApplicationInitializer and AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext  on start up.In onStartup Method you can mention the root context of your application and access the controller mapping thereon.

```
public class CustomWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

 @Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  rootContext.register(RootConfiguration.class);
  ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext);
  container.addListener(contextLoaderListener);

  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  webContext.register(MvcConfiguration.class);
  DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webContext);
  ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
  dispatcher.addMapping("/");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have checked your web.xml for web application and you have correctly set the below configuration

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:pathToYourSpringBeanConfig/channel-application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath: pathToYourSpringBeanConfig/channel-application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Also you need to provide location of your context xml application where you need to tell your context like following details:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan base-package="group.*"></context:component-scan>
```

PS : if you want to access URL without war name you might wanna check this
[Deploy war on Tomcat without the war name in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031537/deploy-war-on-tomcat-without-the-war-name-in-the-url)

Comment: What is the setup if my app is set up with a config class (using @Bean annotations) and not xml?

Comment: in rest controller you can use this annotation

`@EnableWebMvc` an `@ComponentScan `

If you want to get rid of xml application context and web.xml configuration then refer to this please 

[http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html
]

I will try one by myself and let you know the finding.